# R - fitting generalized gamma distribution using fitdistrplus package

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to fit a generalized gamma distribution (weibull, normal, exponential, and lognormal) to daily cases(periods of five months) of Covid-19 data in my country. The code I used to run is written below:

```
#Required library
library("MASS")
library("survival")
library("fitdistrplus")
```

However, I got the below error when I try fitting each distribution.

```
fn_w <- fitdist(daily_cases, "weibull") #weibull distribution
Error in checkparamlist(arg_startfix$start.arg, arg_startfix$fix.arg,  : 
  'start' should not have NA or NaN values.
```

```
fn_g <- fitdist(daily_cases, "gamma") #for gamma distribution
<simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
Error in fitdist(daily_cases, "gamma") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100
```

```
> fn_ln <- fitdist(daily_cases, "lnorm") #for log normal distribution
Error in computing default starting values.
Error in manageparam(start.arg = start, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,  : 
  Error in start.arg.default(obs, distname) : 
  values must be positive to fit a lognormal distribution
```

Only exponential distribution is able to run effectively.

```
> fn_exp <- fitdist(daily_cases, "exp")
> summary(fn_exp)
Fitting of the distribution ' exp ' by maximum likelihood 
Parameters : 
        estimate   Std. Error
rate 0.002949398 0.0002060355
Loglikelihood:  -1044.402   AIC:  2090.803   BIC:  2093.834
```

How can I rectify this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you please `dput(daily_cases)` and paste the output in your question? It is more easy to help with that!

Comment: I second the request for the data. One thing that could be giving you trouble are zero values in the data, which give non-finite log-likelihoods for lognormal, weibull, and gamma distributions (except in the special case of the parameters where those distributions converge to the exponential)

Comment: More generally, (a) you might want to consider a *discrete* distribution for modelling the case distribution; the negative binomial (compound Gamma-Poisson) takes care of the exponential and gamma cases. The lognormal-Poisson is harder but can be fitted via mixed models.  I don't know about the Weibull-Poisson. Most generally (and this is a question for [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com), I wonder what your actual goal is in fitting these distributions ... ?

Comment: If you just want a quick fix, adding a small positive constant to your data (or just to the zeros) would probably solve your immediate problem.

Comment: Thank you so much@BenBolker, when I removed the rows with zero data, the `fitdist(daily_cases, "weibull") ` now run effectively. However both `gamma` and `exp` now return the same error, which is `simpleError in optim(par = vstart, fn = fnobj, fix.arg = fix.arg, obs = data,     gr = gradient, ddistnam = ddistname, hessian = TRUE, method = meth,     lower = lower, upper = upper, ...): function cannot be evaluated at initial parameters>
Error in fitdist(daily_cases, "gamma") : 
  the function mle failed to estimate the parameters, 
                with the error code 100`